# Organize files into folders then subfolders based on filenames

Tags: batch-file, scripting, batch-processing

A set of files have "**Main Folder Name**" (*explicit*) and a **SubFolderName** (*hinted*) in their filenames.

The intention is to just have them organized in new folders by "**Main Folder Name**" and **SubFolderName**
then have all files moved to their corresponding new folders using batch script.

Example:

|>SourceDirectory

```
|>Main Folder Name (0001) S01E01 - FileDescription.bmp
|>Main Folder Name (0001) S01E01 - FileDescription.srt
|>Main Folder Name (0001) S01E02 - FileDescription.bmp
|>Main Folder Name (0001) S01E03 - FileDescription.bmp
|>Main Folder Name (0001) S01E03 - FileDescription.srt
|>Main Folder Name (0007) S03E01 - FileDescription.jpg
|>Main Folder Name (0007) S03E02 - FileDescription.png
|>Main Folder Name (0007) S03E03 - FileDescription.srt
|>Main Folder Name (0012) S25E01 - FileDescription.ico
|>Main Folder Name (0012) S25E02 - FileDescription.txt
```

Intended Outcome

|>SourceDirectory

```
|>Main Folder Name (0001)
    |>SubFolderName 1
        |>Main Folder Name (0001) S01E01 - FileDescription.bmp
        |>Main Folder Name (0001) S01E01 - FileDescription.srt
        |>Main Folder Name (0001) S01E02 - FileDescription.bmp
        |>Main Folder Name (0001) S01E03 - FileDescription.bmp
        |>Main Folder Name (0001) S01E03 - FileDescription.srt

|>Main Folder Name (0007)
    |>SubFolderName 3
        |>Main Folder Name (0007) S03E01 - FileDescription.jpg
        |>Main Folder Name (0007) S03E02 - FileDescription.png
        |>Main Folder Name (0007) S03E03 - FileDescription.srt

|>Main Folder Name (0012)
    |>SubFolderName 25
        |>Main Folder Name (0012) S25E01 - FileDescription.ico
        |>Main Folder Name (0012) S25E02 - FileDescription.txt
```

Spent days trying and taking tips from other posts but my grasp in batch commands proved to be just too basic for this task.

Here's my working pseudo code:

```
1. Take first file
2. Search for the string pattern S??E?? to give away:

    FolderName = All chars on the left of S??
    SubFolderNumber = NumericValue of ?? in S??

3. MakeDir \FolderName\"SubFolderName " + SubFolderNumber
4. Move the file to that new subfolder in step #3
5. Recurse and do steps 1-4 to each file until the end of the list
```

Step #2 may be too simple for the experts in this community but it is not keeping my hands from pulling my hair. :D

Would really appreciate help from anyone who could spare the time and let me keep the little hair I have left.

Comment: Since you've spent so much time attempting to solve the problem, it should be no trouble to edit an attempt into your question using the `edit` button. We may then be able to suggest fixes.

Comment: Thanks for your time Magoo.  What I am attempting to do for that Step#2 is something like below:

 
str = "Main Folder Name (0001) S01E01 - FileDescription.bmp"

set pos= INSTR(str, ") S") 
set FolderName=LEFT(str,pos)
set SubFolderValue=VAL(Mid(str,pos+3,2))
md %FolderName%\SubFolderName %SubFolderValue%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 

rem The following setting for the source directoryis a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"

FOR /L %%s IN (0,1,9) DO FOR /L %%t IN (0,1,9) DO IF EXIST "* S%%s%%tE*" (
 FOR /L %%e IN (0,1,9) DO FOR /L %%f IN (0,1,9) DO IF EXIST "* S%%s%%tE%%e%%f -*" (
  FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('dir /b /a-d "* S%%s%%tE%%e%%f -*"') DO (
   SET "fullname=%%b"
   FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=:" %%q IN ("!fullname: S%%s%%tE%%e%%f =:!") DO (
    IF %%s==0 (
rem     MD "%%q\%%t" 2>nul
rem     MOVE "%%b" "%%q\%%t\" >nul
     ECHO MD "%%q\%%t"
     ECHO MOVE "%%b" "%%q\%%t\"
    ) ELSE (
rem     MD "%%q\%%s%%t" 2>nul
rem     MOVE "%%b" "%%q\%%s%%t\" >nul
     ECHO MD "%%q\%%s%%t"
     ECHO MOVE "%%b" "%%q\%%s%%t\"
    )

   )
  )
 )
)

dir/s

popd

GOTO :EOF
```

This batch is designed to **REPORT** what it intends to do, and should be tested against a test directory before applying it to your live data.

When you are satisfied with the results, remove the `rem` comment keyword from the two `md` and `move` lines to activate. The `echo` lines may be removed if desired.

The `dir/s` at the end simply shows the result.

The key here is the string `S??E??`.

by using `%%s` and `%%t`  each set to `0`..`9` in turn, we can see whether a file named `* S00E*`..`* S99E*` exists. If such a file exists, repeat the recipe using `%%e` and `%%f` to find `* S00E00 -*`..`* S99E99 -*`.

Then grab a list of the filenames using `/b` for names-only and `/a-d` for no directorynames, matching the specific S??E?? string calculated, and assign to `%%b`.

We need to analyse `%%b` so need `delayedexpansion` and transfer to a regular variable `fullname` to do so.

Since the filename does not contain `:`, simply replace the `S??E??` detected by `:` and use `for/f` *tokens* and *delims* options to break the name at the `S??E?? -> :` `%%r` is set to the part after and `%%q` to that before. `%%r` is not used in this process.

Then it's a matter of establishing the subdirectory in `%%q` and the sub-subdirectory in `%%s` or `%%s%%t`.

The `2>nul` suppresses the `directory exists` messages created if a directory is re-created, and the `>nul` on the `move` command suppresses the `1 file(s) moved` message.

Comment: Wow! 

I successfully understood everything - upto the 3rd rem line of your code, at least for now.
The rest of it gave me the same exact effect when my youthful eyes first saw hieroglyphics. 
Fascinated, yes that too.

I'd be needing to look for my spare laptop I last used years ago to get it up and running so i can try this code on as everything else after the header read Greek to me to be honest. 

I plan to prep plenty of test files to test against, enough to get reliable benchmark results.

Comment: I'm a big fan of efficiency and would favor it over readability/maintainability any day of the week and twice on Sunday - at least for codes for personal use as I imagine no management would like any of their programmers deliver codes only themselves understand. Work may have taught me to prefer the codes easily understood by the next person I'll assign them to for enhancements to favor the grander scheme of things.

Comment: Next would be for me to disect each line and try to understand and learn the wisdom behind each of them. I've always been fascinated by how different people approach the same exact problem. Many of them are good and some are better, and the others are simply awesome.

Comment: Beacause of this, I now have something to look forward to to be busy with on my next weekend.

With your reputation, I'm betting the chances of me learning something in what you just shared seems to be inversely equal to the Pope being not Catholic.

And finally, I'll give you a feedback right after I get the results.

I thank you sincerely for your precious time and for the knowledge and technique you selflessly shared, @Magoo.

Comment: And most importantly, I also really appreciate your taking time to thoroughly explain what the code does. It is very detailed, nothing seems to be left out.  Expertly done, very professional technical documentation. It felt like reading from a book.

Comment: I found time to set up and test. It works exactly as spec'd. 
EXTREMELY FAST TOO!!!

Thank you very much! @Magoo

Answer (score 0):

Painfully came up with a ver1.0.

Not fool-proof yet but does the job for now. Kind of slow though. Needs some tuning up from a kind expert out there, maybe a far better approach or even an overhaul.

Your kind suggestions are very much welcome.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%a in (*) DO (
    SET FileName=%%~na
    CALL:findString FileName ") S" pos
    SET /A pos=pos+1
    SET /A pos2=pos+2
    CALL SET "NewFolderName=%%FileName:~0,!pos!%%"
    CALL SET "NewSubFolderNumber=%%FileName:~!pos2!,2%%"
    SET /A NewSubFolderNumber=NewSubFolderNumber
    SET NewSubFolder="%%~pa!NewFolderName!\SubFolderName !NewSubFolderNumber!\"
    SET str="%%~fa" !NewSubFolder!
    MD !NewSubFolder!
    MOVE !str!
)
```

Seek and ye shall find. Found this missing link somewhere in the net just in time to save my remaining lock of hair. ***(Anyone knows why there isn't a built-in INSTR() function in the first place?)***

```
:findString -- returns position of first occurrence of a string in another string, case sensitive, maximum string length is 1023 characters
::          -- %~1: in - varible name of a string to be searched
::          -- %~1: in - string to be found
::          -- %~3: out- return variable name, will be set to position or undefined if string not found
:credit belongs to
:$source http://www.dostips.com
:Posted By: DosItHelp
:Expert
:Posts: 239
:Joined: 18 Feb 2006 19:54

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "pos="
set "str=!%~1!"
for /L %%a in (0,1,1023) do (
   set "s=!str:~%%a!"
   if not defined pos if "%~2!s:*%~2=!"=="!s!" set "pos=%%a"
)
ENDLOCAL & IF "%~3" NEQ "" SET "%~3=%pos%"
GOTO:EOF
```

Hope this can help others.